# PS4 - PSN Network Membership? (Specifically COD: Ghosts)

Tags: psn, ps4

Is there a monthly or annual subscription cost to play online on the PS4? (like there is for xBox Live.)

Although this can be considered a universal question, I'm wondering if it specifically affects playing Call of Duty Ghosts online in muiltplayer.

I have looked on the [PSN Website](http://uk.playstation.com/psn/) and it says `free online gaming` but on an [eBay listing](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/221326631603?ssPageName=STRK:MEWAX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1423.l2649) it's stated a membership is required to play online?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PlayStation Plus (a paid service) is required for online multiplayer play on PS4, but not PS Vita or PS3.

Playing online multiplayer games via the PlayStation 3 is free, and only requires a free PlayStation Network account.

Playing online multiplayer games via the PlayStation 4 requires a [PlayStation Plus](http://playstationplus.com/) account, with very few exceptions (mostly free-to-play online games or online games with separate subscriptions). In that sense, it's reasonable to analogize PlayStation Plus on the PS4 and Xbox LIVE Gold on the Xbox 360 and Xbox One.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Does the PS4 come with 14 days free membership in the box? I'm looking at buying 90 subscription of Playstation Plus for my Bro for Christmas so he can play COD online. Am I correct in thinking it comes as a code that he can just use with his account?

Comment: That is something that would be mentioned on the box or on its online store page. It would be a code though.

Comment: It comes with a code, not sure for how long, but it was either 14 or 30 days.  I think some games may also include ps+ codes, battlefield 4 came with a 7 day code.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Playstation website, you will need [Playstation Plus](http://uk.playstation.com/playstationplus/) to play multiplayer games on the Playstation 4. The "Free online gaming" you see on PSN page applies to PSN as a whole, but not PS4.

Note that *at least* some free-to-play and subscription based games do *not* require Playstation Plus. COD: Ghosts will need PS+.

Comment: I think I heard free-to-play games would be excluded from the requirement, but I can't seem to find any references to that. Someone can confirm or prove me wrong :)

Comment: Neither DCUO nor Warframe require PS Plus, so that may continue to be a pattern.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I read that games that require a paid subscription will also be excluded from the requirement of having PS+. But maybe it was about the Xbox360/One?

Comment: @Nolonar Square Enix has said that FFXIV:ARR won't require Plus on the PS4 either, but that version's not released yet (so "subject to change," yada yada)